# How to use TDateTime parameters in Delphi XE5 DataSnap Rest

Tags: delphi, datasnap

I create a Delphi XE5 DataSnap Rest server (using FireDac components).

All working ok so far except RECEIVING TDATETIME as parameter.

After some research I understand that this Type of Data is not usable in DataSnap (at least direct).

So I want to make a basic function like this:

```
InsertCustomer(aID : Integer; aDateOfBirth : TDateTime) : Integer;
```

How can I make this function because I cannot use the TDateTime...

My idea (request) is to put something similar(identic) with the field that is exported from TDataSet.

when a column TDateTime from a TDataSet is exported is like this... ["2013-10-10 10:47:40.0"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard way to transfer dates and times using either url parameters or JSON. Keep in mind that `TDateTime` is actually a `double` behind the scenes, so defining the method like in your example, the argument should be given as a floating point number in the url.

If you want to accept a date as an ISO8601 string, you have to define the argument as a `string` type and manually do the conversion. Here is one function I use in my own code for exactly this type of problem.

```
uses
  Soap.XSBuiltIns;

function ISODateStrToDate(DateStr: string): TDateTime;
var
  xsDate: TXSDate;
begin
  xsDate := TXSDate.Create;
  try
    xsDate.XSToNative(DateStr);
    Exit(xsDate.AsDate);
  finally
    xsDate.Free;
  end;
end;
```

This function throws away the time portion of the ISO8601 string. I don't need it in most cases.

If you need the time portion, you can possibly use

```
function XMLTimeToDateTime(const XMLDateTime: InvString; AsUTCTime: Boolean = False): TDateTime;
```

this is from the same Soap.XSBuiltIns unit, however **BE WARNED!** This function only works correctly for full ISO8601 strings which includes full time zone information (the +01:00 or -05:00 ending part). For your example ISO8601 datetime it will act as if you have given the time in UTC time and it will try to convert it to a TDateTime value in local time.

Comment: tks for answer ... so I guess it will be string because in more "human readable" in case of errors.

Comment: The main problem is that there is simply not an accepted standard way to transfer dates. REST isn't a solid standard, it is just catch-all term used to describe an HTTP RPC API. JSON specifically does not define a standard date format either. That is why you have to make a decission yourself on what you support for your API.
You could define your method so that year, month, day, etc. are individual integer arguments. Then the corresponding HTTP call would look like this:

    /datasnap/rest/TMyController/InsertCustomer/252/2014/2/4/17/36